# How can I start printing a PDF at a page before 'page 1'?

Tags: pdf

How do I start printing the PDF from Logical Page no. 5? See screenshot beneath.

Foxit PhantomPDF labels this PDF's first 35 pages all as 'Cover', which thwarts selecting or distinguishing these 35 pages.

Nitro Pro labels in Roman numerals, but bizarrely forbids any, pages before "1" to be printed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some PDF readers, such as Foxit Reader, number the pages starting with `1`,
where `1` is the real first page, which includes also the cover.

Other PDF readers, such as Adobe Acrobat, let you use the roman numbers that
you see, so you may print for example a range of `ii-9`.

Whatever your PDF reader does, try all options or look in the Help,
since it is sure that printing a part of the file is always possible.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't clinch how this helps? I'm seeking more specific advice than 'Whatever your PDF reader does, try all options or look in the Help, since it is sure that printing a part of the file is always possible.'.

Comment: Have you tried both numbering systems in your PDF reader (which is what?) ?